How to prove this inequality (model quantization)?
Some conditions and definitions which may not be of use :


$\pi_j^{t|s}:=P_{Y_t|\{X_t,X_s^{replay}\}}(y_t=j|x_t)$ stand for the prediction probability of the t-th task data $x_{t}$ on the j-th class, incorporated with the training of replay data from the s-th task $X_s^{repaly}$, where $s < t$.
$\pi_j^{t}:=P_{Y_t|\{X_t\}}(y_t=j|x_t)$ stand for the prediction probability without replay data from the s-th task $X_s^{replay}$.
Denote $n_j^t$ as the sample size of $X_t$ on the j-th class and $r_j^s$ as the sample size of $X_s^{replay}$ on the j-th class. If $r_j^s \leq \delta_j n_j^t$, $\forall j$, where $\delta_j\in[0,1]$ is the replay ratio on the j-th class and $r_j^s$.


Given:
$$\pi_j^{t|s}-\pi_j^=\frac{P_{\{X_t,X_s^{replay}\}|Y_t}(x_t|y_t=j)}{P_{\{X_t,X_s^{replay}\}}(x_t)}\cdot\frac{r_j^s+n_j^t}{\sum_{i=1}^K(r_i^s+n_i^t)}-\frac{P_{X_t|Y_t}(x_t|y_t=j)}{P_{X_t}(x_t)}\cdot\frac{n_j^t}{\sum_{i=1}^Kn_i^t}$$
I want to prove that:
$$|\pi_j^{t|s}-\pi_j^t|\ \leq \max \left\{\frac{P_{\{X_t,X_s^{replay}\}|Y_t}(x_t|j)}{P_{\{X_t,X_s^{replay}\}}(x_t)},\frac{P_{X_t|Y_t}(x_t|j)}{P_{X_t}(x_t)}\right\} \cdot \left|\frac{r_j^s+n_j^t}{\sum_{i=1}^K(r_i^s+n_i^t)}-\frac{n_j^t}{\sum_{i=1}^Kn_i^t}\right|$$
I failed to prove this in a model quantization paper's support material, whose title is Overcoming Forgetting Catastrophe in Quantization-Aware Training. The latter equality that I want to prove is derived from the former equation that is given directly without details in this paper, so I try to figure out why and how.
Be grateful for your help.
